# Subtract business days (with holidays) in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have a dataframe:

| Case_no | Event_ID | Date | Type | Done_by |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2023-01-01 | Email Sent | Customer |
| 1 | 2 | 2023-01-02 | Response | Agent |
| 1 | 3 | 2023-01-03 | Email Sent | Customer |
| 1 | 4 | 2023-01-10 | Response | Agent |
| 2 | 5 | 2023-01-02 | Email Sent | Customer |
| 2 | 6 | 2023-01-04 | Email Sent | Customer |

I have found a function to apply that flags up whether an email has a response and whether one has had a response in 5 days as follows. assuming the above is df3:

```
def f(x):
    
    m = x['Done_by'].eq('Customer')
    for k, v in x.loc[m, 'Date'].items():
        s = x[~m].loc[k:, 'Date'].sub(v).dt.days
        x.loc[k, 'Response?'] = not s.empty
        x.loc[k, 'Response_Within_Five_Days'] = s.lt(5).any()
        #NEED TO ADD WORKING DAY AND BANK HOLIDAY EXCEPTIONS AS 

    return x

df4 = df3.reset_index(drop=True)

df4 =  df4.groupby('Reference #').apply(f)

df4
```

This will return

| Case_no | Event_ID | Date | Type | Done_by | Response? | Response_Within_Five_Days |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2023-01-01 | Email Sent | Customer | TRUE | TRUE |
| 1 | 2 | 2023-01-02 | Response | Agent | nan | NAN |
| 1 | 3 | 2023-01-03 | Email Sent | Customer | TRUE | FALSE |
| 1 | 4 | 2023-01-10 | Response | Agent | NAN | NAN |
| 2 | 5 | 2023-01-02 | Email Sent | Customer | FALSE | FALSE |
| 2 | 6 | 2023-01-04 | Email Sent | Customer | FALSE | FALSE |

I also know that I can add and subtract business days using the following code:

```
import requests
import json
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from pandas.tseries.offsets import *
from datetime import *
import holidays

uk_holidays = holidays.GB(subdiv='England',years = [2022,2023,2024,2025])


myholidays = [holiday.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') for holiday in uk_holidays]


myholidays

holidays= myholidays

bday_uk = CustomBusinessDay(holidays=holidays)



ts = pd.Timestamp(2022, 12, 23)
ts+(2 *bday_uk )

result : Timestamp('2022-12-29 00:00:00')
```

How would I go about swapping the

```
 s = x[~m].loc[k:, 'Date'].sub(v).dt.days
```

for something that would subtract business days instead? I have read about creating a custom accessor but I am not going to lie when I say I was not able to wrap my head around it enough to do what I want. Would I have to create a custom accessor or is there an easier way to subtract business days in my function?

Comment: What is your expected ouput?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to use the `pandas.tseries.offsets.CustomBusinessDay` class to subtract business days in your function.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from pandas.tseries.offsets import CustomBusinessDay
from datetime import date
import holidays

uk_holidays = holidays.GB(subdiv='England',years = [2022,2023,2024,2025])
myholidays = [holiday.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') for holiday in uk_holidays]
bday_uk = CustomBusinessDay(holidays=myholidays)

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Case_no': [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2],
    'Event_ID': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
    'Date': ['2023-01-01', '2023-01-02', '2023-01-03', '2023-01-10', '2023-01-02', '2023-01-04'],
    'Type': ['Email Sent', 'Response', 'Email Sent', 'Response', 'Email Sent', 'Email Sent'],
    'Done_by': ['Customer', 'Agent', 'Customer', 'Agent', 'Customer', 'Customer']
})

df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

def f(x):
    m = x['Done_by'].eq('Customer')
    for k, v in x.loc[m, 'Date'].items():
        s = x[~m].loc[k:, 'Date'].apply(lambda d: bday_uk.rollback(d)).sub(bday_uk.rollback(v)).dt.days
        x.loc[k, 'Response?'] = not s.empty
        x.loc[k, 'Response_Within_Five_Days'] = (s >= -5).any()
    return x

df = df.groupby('Case_no').apply(f).reset_index(drop=True)

print(df)
```

which will return

```
   Case_no  Event_ID       Date        Type    Done_by  Response?  Response_Within_Five_Days
0        1         1 2023-01-01  Email Sent   Customer       True                        True
1        1         2 2023-01-02    Response      Agent      False                       False
2        1         3 2023-01-03  Email Sent   Customer       True                       False
3        1         4 2023-01-10    Response      Agent      False                       False
4        2         5 2023-01-02  Email Sent   Customer      False                       False
5        2         6 2023-01-04  Email Sent   Customer      False                       False
```